# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1 - Spring MVC Project Template Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, intellij-idea

I'm playing with Spring Framework in IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.1.

In IntelliJ I choose: File -> New Project -> Spring -> Spring MVC -> Create Project From Template. It creates default Spring project with configuration of deploying WAR:exploded to Tomcat Server. I change nothing to the default configuration. It builds and deploys correctly, but the result is following:

**HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet mvc-dispatcher threw exception
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Files generated by IntelliJ are quite concise:

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>

</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello world!");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

This occurs on two different machines, under Ubuntu 12.04 and Windows 7. 
I downloaded some other Spring MVC projects from the Internet and they run just fine, so I guess the problem is with the files IntelliJ generates automatically, which I find weird. However, I was not able to find which part causes this problem.

**EDIT:**
Full stack trace from Tomcat (7.0.52) log:

```
kwi 23, 2014 11:48:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

kwi 23, 2014 11:48:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet mvc-dispatcher
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>    (SimpleMetadataReader.java:52)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:80)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:101)
at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:76)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:298)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:300)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:230)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:153)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:130)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:285)
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:223)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:630)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:598)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:661)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:517)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:458)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:138)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:864)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:134)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

kwi 23, 2014 11:48:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: there ain't no closing beans tag in mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml

Comment: there should be a problem with the way you deploy it. I followed all your steps and deployed on a vanilla Tomcat 7 and it works fine.

Comment: @Evgeni It is present in the code, but was invisible in my post, I've corrected it.

Comment: Is there more to the exception stack trace? Contains nested exception?

Comment: @CodeClimber I added full stack trace from Tomcat Log

Comment: is the stack trace complete? It vaguely refers to log coming from Tomcat and I'm sure it's working fine on a vanilla Tomcat 7.0.53.

Comment: @dimitrisli Yep, that's it (the part I've pasted repeats 2 more times, but I only pasted single instance of each exception)

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and changing the JAVA SDK (File >> Project 
Structure >> Projects)from 1.8 to 1.6 or 1.7 helped remove the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add the listener class on web.xml, its the `ContextLoaderListener`

after your `</servlet-mapping>` add:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

If you get errors about the mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml location add this to the top of `<servlet>`:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Docs:

[ContextLoaderListener](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.5.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoaderListener.html)